# Web Scraping Assistance

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a complete novice. No experience in computer programming. As a result, the opportunity cost of learning anything--like Scrapy--is very high, so I don't want to spend hours doing dead end work (***ex.*** I spent all day just installing Scrapy because I am an idiot).

My research involves collecting data from a database on charitable organizations (http://www.charitynavigator.org/). Basically, my program needs to be able to look at a list of links that connect to a charity "fact sheet"; then, the program needs to extract desired data, and categorize that data.

***My main technical question is*** can a program like Scrapy recognize that a number (100,000) next to a term (assets) means that the charity has 100,000 USD in assets. Or at least place 100,000 under assets category?

Apologies for the trivial nature of the question. I am just very tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> My main technical question is can a program like Scrapy recognize that a number (100,000) next to a term (assets) means that the charity has 100,000 USD in assets. Or at least place 100,000 under assets category?

Yes it can. I took a brief look at that site and it doesn't seem like it would be too bad. The financial data all seems to take the form:

```
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contributions, Gifts &amp; Grants</td>
        <td align="right">$186,659,755</td>
      </tr>
```

As you can see, all of the financial numbers are paired with an element describing them. That being said, writing such a scraper (especially using Scrapy) will be difficult for someone with no programming experience.

Assuming you value your time, you might be better off just copy+pasting the numbers by hand into an Excel spreadsheet or paying someone else to do so. You may also wish to consider paying someone to write the scraper for you.

Scrapy is amazing and makes many things easier to do, but there is a lot of cognitive overload for a non-programmer to learn just to write one scraper. Especially considering you won't be making much use of the features Scrapy adds over just writing something from scratch. If you *do* decide to go that route, I'd recommend using `lxml` to extract the data you want from the page.

I recommend that first, you [Learn Python](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/), then [learn about generators](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/). (they are used extensively throughout Scrapy) Once you're done with both of those, go work through the [Official Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).